# Google maps api continuously loading in console

Tags: google-maps, google-api, firebug

I am using google maps API and included below link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Below link is continuously loading in console under Net tab in firebug so my browser tab not stopping to show loading icon.

http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@207000000&src=apiv3&hl=en-US&x=49&y=97&z=8&s=Gali&style=api|smartmaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually may happen only when you initialize the map before the window has finished loading.

So my first suggestion would be to initialize the map on `window.onload`
When this is not the case in your implementation and you already initialize the map onload, you may call

```
window.stop()
```

...immediately before you initialize the map.

**But Note:** this will stop all active loading-processes for any ressources, it's exactly the same behaviour as when you press the browsers stop-button or <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Comment: In addition to this answer, I add the code to used: `window.onload = function() { initialiseMap(); };` See [GMap API Handling Event examples for more infos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=fr)

Answer (score 0):

Strange! I tried it in Firefox and works fine, and it completes loading. It may have something to do with loading a cached copy, try clearing your cache and then loading again.

I wouldn't suggest `window.stop()` just yet, use it as a last resort.